# Spotify API - Angular 4

Tags: api, angular, spotify

How can i to convert this: new Buffer(client_id + ':' + client_secret).toString('base64')

to Angular?

I need de access token but doesn't work.

Docs: https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/

Comment: same issue here,  :(

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it by passing it through the btoa() method. For example:

```
btoa(client_id + ':' + client_secret)
```